# Twilio dial number with extra digits

Tags: php, rest, twilio

Is it possible to dial the extra digits used with `<gather>` on the initial call, in affect bypassing the need to request the user to press numbers whilst in the call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="handle-response.php" timeout="5" method="GET" numDigits="2">
        <Say>Enter your number</Say>
    </Gather>
    <!-- If customer doesn't input anything, prompt and try again. -->
    <Say>Sorry, I didn't get your response.</Say>
</Response>
```

So calling `[YOURNUMBER]1234` the result would pass `handle-response.php?From=X&To=X&Digits=1234`

Comment: I'd suggest contacting help@twilio.com - there doesn't seem to be anything in their documentation that explains if this is possible or not. Would be interested to know if it is possible though!

Comment: Hey, Twilio employee here. Let me make sure I understand you: You want a user to be able to dial MYNUMBER1234 and pass the extra digits (1234) straight into the gather tag, without them having to wait to connect first?

If this is the case - it wouldn't work, as you're dialling a number and the telephone network won't necessarily discriminate between number and extra digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The answer is found by looking at the call logs in your Twilio account. As a test, I attempted dialing extra digits when calling one of my Twilio phone numbers and saw no indication that the extra digits were forwarded in any of the request parameters.